# Adobe Flash professional vs Eclipse vs HTML5 for android apps

Tags: android, eclipse, html, actionscript-3, flash

I have been using the flash pro for 6 years now, and I find it very easy to create any kind of application and game (except 3D ones). The flash pro says that is can compile cross platform natively in Android (and iOs too), so am in a dilemma (or trilemma), should I use:
1. The flash pro IDE which I know very good
2. Should I learn Eclipse which I hear is ideal for Android apps or
3. Should I make the app with HTML5, jquery mobile, etc and compile it with PhoneGap?

The app I was to develop is quite simple, it has a list of POIs, categories, (from online database) and it shows them on map (flash pro may have to use stageview for that), so the graphic processing required should be minimal. It may also cache some POIs when downloaded on phone.

Please answer the question in relation to:
- Speed/responsiveness of the app 
- How much "native"/professional the app will be
- Feature-wise, would all the features be there
- Debugging

Thank you,
Panos

Comment: If it's simple, HTML is honestly the route I would take. If you're developing a game or something, you should actually be looking at something like Unity considering you're comfortable with the Flash Professional IDE.

Comment: It is a simple app, with no big gpu usage, so I could use HTML5, my only concern with phoneGap is the app being responsive (although there are some tips to make it as responsive as it can be). I am very comfortable with flash, but I have to use stageview for maps and poi on the map, and I have a concern about smooth scrolling..

Comment: HTML with the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/). Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always going to be able to get the best results with the most native approach (eclipse) as long as you can handle the IDE and language. You have a good deal of experience with flash and if you don't have much or any with Java you may have trouble getting into using Java.

Here's a simple breakdown though:

**Flash:**

- Great for apps that serve as a web frontend.
- Supports most common android features.
- Doing anything heavy in processing or too custom tends to get bad performance.
- You are abstracted from what the app is really doing and therefore have less control.

**Java:**

- You are using the native language and therefore can use android to it's fullest extent.
- You will find plenty of help for any problem you run into and it's much easier to debug more complicated apps.
- Better performance in most app usages, especially for more complex apps.
- Not cross-platform though you don't seem to care about that.

**PhoneGap:**

- I have no experience for this but I would assume it's similar to the Flash approach.
- Probably really good for Web Frontends.

The choice is really just dependent on what you feel would best suit your current knowledge and goals for the app.

I would strongly recommend just learning Java and using Eclipse as it will always be as good and responsive as you can design it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was very clarifying. A noob question: what do you mean exactly by web frontnend? (I know what it means, but I don't get if you mean if the app would have to be simple like a webpage or sth like that..)

Comment: No I mean nothing of the simplicity of the App, more of the usage of the App. A web frontend would be the part of the web-page / app you see. A server would do all of the computing and accessing of the database and whatnot in the background, typically via a API.